# Correct Notation for Limits of Function Composition

Tags: calculus, limits, notation, function-and-relation-composition

When taking the limit of function composition, what is the best way to write the intermediate step?

Suppose we have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that are continuous where $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=b$ and $\lim_{x \to b}  f(x)=c$  and we are trying to evaluate $\lim_{x \to a}f(g(x))$, how do we write out the intermediate step in the following evaluation?

$\lim_{x \to a}f(g(x))=\lim_{x \to b} f(x)=c$

or

$\lim_{x \to a}f(g(x))=\lim_{g(x) \to b} f(g(x))=c$

The first is uncomfortable because the $x$ variables are not referring to the same variable, but the second seems unusual with $g(x) \to b$ being written under the limit.

Or is there a third way that is still better notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general both notation are fine, I would prefer the following

$$\lim_{x \to a}f(g(x))=\lim_{y \to b} f(y)=c$$

since $f$ is continuous we can also use the following

$$\lim_{x \to a}f(g(x))=f\left(\lim_{x \to a} g(x)\right)=f(b)=c$$

Comment: We are given $f$ and $g$ are continuous (although we are not told that $a$ is in the domain of $g$ nor that $g(a)$ is in the domain of $f$, so neither are forced continuous where we are interested).  So perhaps prefer the second option.

Comment: @EricTowers I agree with you! I fix it in that way.